# Using selenium to click a button that has a unicode character as its label

Tags: xpath, selenium, unicode

As you can imagine, I have no access to the web page code.  There is a drop-down button that I need to click on and when I'm looking at the source, the only unique feature of that button is that it's an INPUT element with a VALUE of ▼

```
<input class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitArrowButtonInner" type="text" role="presentation" readonly="readonly" tabindex="-1" value="▼ "></input>
```

That's all I have to work with.  When I try using the symbol itself (▼), my code throws a syntax error so I'd imagine some unicode value (U+25BC) would be in order here but I can't get it to work.

This is the HTML:

```
<div id="widget_iopri" class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitLeft dijitTextBox dijitComboBox dijitValidationTextBox" role="combobox" widgetid="iopri" aria-expanded="false">
 <div class="dijitReset dijitRight dijitButtonNode dijitArrowButton dijitDownArrowButton dijitArrowButtonContainer" role="presentation" data-dojo-attach-point="_buttonNode, _popupStateNode" popupactive="true">
  <input class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitArrowButtonInner" type="text" role="presentation" readonly="readonly" tabindex="-1" value="▼ "></input>
 </div>
 <div class="dijitReset dijitValidationContainer">
  <input class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitValidationIcon dijitValidationInner" type="text" role="presentation" readonly="readonly" tabindex="-1" value="Χ "></input>
 </div>
 <div class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitInputContainer">
  <input id="iopri" class="dijitReset dijitInputInner" type="text" aria-haspopup="true" role="textbox" data-dojo-attach-point="textbox,focusNode" autocomplete="off" aria-required="true" tabindex="0" aria-invalid="false" value="idle" aria-owns="iopri_popup"></input>
  <input type="hidden" name="iopri" value="3"></input>
 </div>
</div>
```

I've tried:

```
//div[@id='widget_iopri']/div[@data-dojo-attach-point='_buttonNode']
//div[@id='widget_iopri']/div[@class='dijitDownArrowButton']/input[@class='dijitArrowButtonInner']
//div[@id='widget_iopri']/div[@class='dijitDownArrowButton']/input
```

The problem is that I can't get too specific because the classes & id's are re-used everywhere and the only thing that is unique is the ▼.

Comment: Can you select it by xpath instead?

Comment: I added more HTML specifics to the original question as a response.

Comment: Can you share the url?

Comment: I can't.  It's internal but there is no chance that our company will change it for me.  If they would even entertain the idea, it would probably take months to implement.  Fun, I know.  Sorry :\

Answer (score 0):

I found an xpath that seems to work:

```
find(:xpath, "//div[@id='widget_iopri']/div[@data-dojo-attach-point='_buttonNode, _popupStateNode']/input").click
```

Thanks for the suggestion, @Pat Meeker!